# Disable a Link after it is clicked --no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to disable my link when it is clicked .
checkletter is a function which checks if letter is available in word for my hangman game.

```
     <span id="A"><a href="javascript:checkLetter('A');">A</a></span>
```

i tried using this
         a.visited{
         display:none;
          }

it doesn't seem to be working

Please advice!!

Comment: It would be `a:visited` instead of `a.visited` but it'll hide the link, not deactivate it

Comment: To be clear are you trying to disable the function from being called, or change the appearance of the link?

Comment: sorry it was just a typo i used a:visited{

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelector('#A a').style.pointerEvents = 'none';`

** http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Not gonna downvote since it's true, but this limits cross-browser compatibility.  Nice find though.

Comment: Agree, this isn't cross browser solution now (thanks, IE!). That's why I've posted link to caniuse.com :) `link.href = null` [1] solution would be the best one if browser compatibility is an issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829143/disable-a-link-after-it-is-clicked-no-jquery/20829186#20829186

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use your checkLetter function?

```
function checkLetter(letter) {
  // Do stuff
  document.getElementById(letter).style.display = "none";
}
```

**update**

To disable the link instead of hiding it (as requested in comment) see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/J67eY/1/

Comment: thanks..this seems to be working but is there a way i can disable my link instead of making it invisible

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

### [Very Fun Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6BzP/)

**Long story short:**  assuming `link` is assigned to your link:

```
link.href = null;
```

will disable the link entirely.

I got excited and posted too quickly.  Here's what you want :)

```
var links = document.links || document.anchors || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, j = links.length; i < j; i++) {
    addEvent(links[i], 'click', disable);
}

function disable(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        link = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
    checkLetter(link.innerHTML);
    link.href = null;
    return false;
}

function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
    return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
}
```

This code also assumes you removed `javascript:checkLetter('A')` from your link's `href=""`.  Instead, I call it inside the function using the letter that it is (`link.innerHTML`)